# Real analysis : Existence of intervals that contains a interval in it's interior that satisfy a property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working through *Measure and Integral: An Introduction to Real Analysis* to prepare for my real analysis course and came across these in proofs:

> Given $\varepsilon > 0$, let ${I_{k}^*}$ be an interval containing $I_{k}$ in it's interior such that $v(I_{k}^*) \leq (1+\varepsilon)v(I_{k})$

I don't know to prove such interval $I_{k}^*$ exists. Any help or suggested reading material is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If $I_k=(a,b)$ take $I_k^{*}=(a-\delta, b+\delta)$ with $0 <\delta <\frac {\epsilon} 2 (b-a)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much!